# maven clean install not taking jar from local repository

Tags: java, maven, command-prompt

I am trying to run `mvn clean install` command from command line. At one location it is trying to download the jar from remote location.

```
[INFO] Deleting directory C:\Users\212368997\ruchita_pdm_laptop\vobs\iui\src\newsrc\xr-service-impl\target
[INFO] [resources:resources]
[INFO] Using 'ISO-8859-1' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
Downloading:     http://3.204.29.172:8081/artifactory/repo1/com/gehc/xr/wf/DuifEventsData/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/DuifEventsData-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[WARNING] Unable to get resource 'com.gehc.xr.wf:DuifEventsData:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'  from repository xr-workflow-repository (http://3.204.29.172:8081/artifactory/repo
1): Error transferring file: Connection timed out: connect
Downloading:     http://3.204.29.172:8081/artifactory/repo1/com/gehc/xr/wf/DuifEventIdVal/1.0.0-  SNAPSHOT/DuifEventIdVal-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

and the process halts.
I have

> DuifEventsData-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

jar at the local repository in .m2 folder then also it is trying to download the jar from [(http://3.204.29.172:8081/...]
what is the solution for this ?

Comment: What is the *full path* in your `.m2` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try running maven offline `mvn clean install -o`. This will pick jars from your local repository i.e in .m2. As you mentioned jar is already in local repo, and if all other dependencies are also in local, this will work.

Comment: mvn clean install -o -Dmaven.test.skip=true solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

When snapshot depedencies are used, maven checks stable or updated depedencies.And that is what happening in your casse.
In you repository config in pom.xml you need to set updaate policy for Snapshot as:

```
<repository>
    <id>a-repository</id>
    <url>http://3.204.29.172:8081/artifactory/repo</url>
    <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
    </snapshots>
</repository>
```

`<updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>` .. This will disable the check and download for snapshot dependency

For more details [refer](http://maven.apache.org/ref/2.2.1/maven-settings/settings.html)

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the remote repository is not defined in your project POM under  or in $MAVEN_HOME/conf/settings.xml

Answer (score -1):

maybe the jar shouldn't be placed in .m2 folder, it should be placed in where it should be.
Please use mvn -X to print debug information, maybe some clues would be found.

Comment: The same .m2 repository I am using in eclipse and it gives no problem.

Answer (score -4):

Please check your settings.xml in .m2 folder.